# Wordpress multisite with same login for different domain

Tags: php, wordpress, session, cookies

I have configured a wordpress multisite based on two different domains: website.net and website.com

Everything works as expected except for the login functionality (not synchronized).
If I'm logged in website.net and I want to access website.com dashboard I have to login again, same for the frontend.
I'm currently using wordpress 5.3.2

This is my multisite configuration in wp-config.php

```
 /* Multisite */
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'website.net'); 
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

There seems to always be a bit on confusion on this topic. Perhaps WordPress could do a better job guiding it's users in this process. Although, I suppose Multi-site wasn't intended to be used for TLD's.

So first of all, I would [install WordPress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress), [setup multisite](https://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network), and configure it as a subdomain network configuration.

Here's a sample configuration for your `wp-config.php` file in the base directory of your WordPress installation:

```
/* Multisite */
define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );
define( 'MULTISITE', true );
define( 'SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', true );
define( 'DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'www.primary-domain.com' );
define( 'PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/' );
define( 'SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1 );
define( 'BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1 );
```

Then, here's the basic configuration for your `.htaccess` file as a subdomain configuration, in the base directory of your WordPress installation:

```
# BoF WordPress

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

# EoF WordPress
```

Now in order to get TLD's to work properly, I've had to make some additional configurations to the `wp-config.php` file like this:

```
define( 'COOKIE_DOMAIN', '' );
define( 'ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH', '/' );
define( 'COOKIEPATH', '/' );
define( 'SITECOOKIEPATH', '/' );
```

That's it with the WordPress specific configurations.

Personally, I like to have one Apache Virtual Host for the primary domain in the network and then configure that virtual host with alias domains. Each alias domain being one of the additional sites in your network.

However you end up tweaking your setup, you need each domain's DNS to resolve to the same web server, and each domain to be pointed to the same directory the primary domain is installed with WordPress. Each domain in your network needs to point to the same web server with DNS records and share the same directory path for the files used by WordPress.

Once you've got everything configured and setup properly as discussed above. Log into your WordPress administration area and navigate to the Network administration area to add a new site into your network.

When you go to add a site, it will enforce you to add the website as if it were a sub domain under your primary domain. Just roll with it. Enter something temporary.

Once the site has been added, then go find it under the list of sites in your network. Click edit on that specific site. Now, you can fully 100% change the domain name of that website. That's when you would put the actual domain name for this TLD site.

I know it's a bit of trickery to do it that way, but it works and you don't need to use any plugins.

Here is the original answer : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/251116/how-to-use-wordpress-multisite-with-different-domain-names/251146#251146

Comment: Hi Dlk,
already tried with this answer without success: I get redirect error loop when tried to access to a created subsite (example website.com/de/wp-admin).
I think the issue could be related to cookie config or session. 
Any hints would be appreciated. 
Thank you.

Comment: turn `define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);` and open your wp-config.php file and add this line after the other code you added to create the network:
`define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);`

Comment: Tried as suggest, still no success. Same error: TOO MANY REDIRECTS.

/* Multisite */
define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );
define( 'MULTISITE', true );
define( 'SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false );
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'website.net'); 
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);

define( 'COOKIE_DOMAIN', '' );
define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
define( 'ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH', '/' );
define( 'COOKIEPATH', '/' );
define( 'SITECOOKIEPATH', '/' );

Comment: Delete all suggestions about cookies from answer and add what I suggest in previous comment! Clear your cookies and try it. if still not working then try this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/share-logins/#installation